# linq to sql loadwith vs associatewith

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

what is the difference between loadwith and associatewith. From the articles i read it seems that loadwith is used to load addition data (eg all orders for the customers). While AssociateWith is used to filter data.

Is that a correct understanding? Also it will be nice if someone can explain this with an example based explanation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`LoadWith` is used to perform an **eager load** of an association as opposed to the default **lazy load**.

Normally, associations are loaded the first time you reference them.  That means if you select 100 `Order` instances, and then do something with each of their `Details`, you're actually performing 101 `SELECT` operations against the database.  On the other hand, if the `LoadOptions` specify `LoadWith<Order>(o => o.Details)`, then it's all done in a single `SELECT` with an added `JOIN`.

`AssociateWith` doesn't have any effect on **when** the association is loaded, just **what** is loaded.  It adds a `WHERE` clause every time you load an association.

As you say, `AssociateWith` is used to *automatically* filter data.  Typically you'd use this if you know that an association has a very large number of elements and you only need a specific subset of them.  Again, it's mainly a performance optimization, just a different kind.

Comment: This line made it clear for me "AssociateWith doesn't have any effect on when the association is loaded, just what is loaded".

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Yes your understanding is correct; AssociateWith filters data before queries whereas LoadWith returns associated objects in the query. The reason for doing LoadWith is so you can return associated objects in 1 single query. Otherwise extra db calls will be made at the time when you iterate over your associated objects.

Try different examples yourself and take a look at the SQL generated through Profiler or some other logger. Remember that these options need to be set on your DataContext before you do any queries.

Have a look at the examples in the below links (MSDN). I've just copied the examples they use there.

[LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx)

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.Orders);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;

var londonCustomers = from cust in db.Customers
                      where cust.City == "London"
                      select cust;
```

[AssociateWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.associatewith.aspx)

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.AssociateWith<Customer>(
    c => c.Orders.Where(p => p.ShippedDate != DateTime.Today));
db.LoadOptions = dlo;

var custOrderQuery = from cust in db.Customers
                     where cust.City == "London"
                     select cust;
```

Comment: Why did I use AssociateWith but later on get the cannot access disposed object exception? Do I have to do LoadWith and AssociateWith together to get the eager loading?